# Difference between Clustered PK vs Nonclustered PK + Clustered index on PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

As the title says, is there any the difference between creating a

- Clustered PK on Id

vs creating

- Nonclustered PK on Id
- Clustered Index on Id

If I create a Nonclustered PK and a Clustered Index on the PK, would that mean that the table would need to maintain two indexes because a non clustered PK would still be indexed?

Comment: Can you provide any context as to why you are asking this question? It doesn't appear that option 2 would provide any benefits, and yes as you say there are now 2 indexes to be maintained.

Comment: OK, I can think of one benefit, being able to change your clustered index without having to drop your foreign keys.